# Efficient way to select few or all records from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query optimization problem. Let's say there is a table which has all the invoices. Using a TVP (Table Valued Parameter) I'd like to select few records by providing 1..n ids, or return all records by providing a single id with the value of -1.

```
    DECLARE @InvoiceIdSet AS dbo.TBIGINT;
    INSERT INTO @InvoiceIdSet VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4)
    --INSERT INTO @InvoiceIdSet VALUES (-1)

    SELECT TOP 100
            I.Id ,
            Number ,
            DueDate ,
            IssuedDate ,
            Amount ,
            Test3
    FROM    dbo.Invoices I
    --WHERE   EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
    --                 FROM   @InvoiceIdSet
    --                 WHERE  I.Id = ID
    --                        OR ID = -1 )
    --CROSS APPLY @InvoiceIdSet s WHERE i.Id = s.ID OR s.ID = -1
    JOIN @InvoiceIdSet S ON S.ID = I.Id OR S.ID=-1
```

Regardless of which method of selection I use, the query performs quite efficiently, until I start using the OR operator, at which point it starts taking a very long time to return few records, but all records are being returned real fast.

Any pointers and suggestions will be highly appreciated.

[image: Without OR]

[image: With OR]

The first plan is without OR, the second is with OR.

**UPDATE:**
After fiddling with different options, I have arrived at this solution as the fastest performing, regardless of number of parameters.

First change the UserDefinedTableType to include a primary key index:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TBIGINT] AS TABLE(
[ID] [bigint] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
)
```

The select statement now looks like this:

```
SELECT TOP 100
    I.Id ,
    Number ,
    DueDate ,
    IssuedDate ,
    Amount ,
    Test3
FROM    dbo.Invoices I
WHERE   I.ID IN ( SELECT    S.ID
              FROM      @InvoiceIdSet S
              WHERE     S.ID <> -1
              UNION ALL
              SELECT    S.ID
              FROM      dbo.Invoices S
              WHERE     EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                                 FROM   @InvoiceIdSet
                                 WHERE  ID = -1 ) )
```

The plans got much bigger, but performance is almost constant, between few (first plan) and all (second plan) records.

[image: Few Records]

[image: All Records]

As you can see the plans are now identical and return the required records in less than a second from 1M rows.

I'd love to hear what the community thinks about this solution.

Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Do an explain, and see what those ORs are causing.

Comment: Already did. No clue.

Comment: Why do you have  ID = -1 separated?  Can the Invoices table have an ID of -1?  All of your chpices are going to result in a cartesian join, which I don't think is what you want.

Comment: @Andrew - A cartesian join against a single row table though.

Comment: The optimal plan for "All" is different from the optimal plan for "Some" so the easiest and best way would be to pass a separate parameter for "All". Then just have an `IF ... ELSE` or (if 2008+) use `WHERE @All = 'true' OR EXISTS .... OPTION(RECOMPILE)`

Comment: I did try to use a parameter, i.e. "CROSS APPLY @InvoiceIdSet s WHERE i.Id = s.ID OR @AllInvoices=1", but the performance continues to suffer. OR is throwing the query optimizer of balance ...

Comment: It's Monday morning and all, so maybe I'm confused.  Won't it be a cartesian against the Invoices table?  Select from invoices i, @InvoiceIdSet s where s.id = -1.

Comment: @Darek - If you are on 2008+ then you can use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` for that case though. It will sniff the value of a scalar variable/parameter at recompile but not look inside the TVP.

Comment: @Andrew - Yes but a cross join of a one row table with an X row table produces X rows. And that is the intention here. A single -1 row means "return all"

Comment: Got it.  I can't work this out in my head, but could you try to use a case statement in the where clause to avoid the OR?

Comment: CASE is exactly what I want to avoid. It is what we have today, and the SQL is just plain ugly. Also, set based operations should be faster than CASE any day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to accept my own answer here:

```
DECLARE @InvoiceIdSet AS TBIGINT
--INSERT  INTO @InvoiceIdSet
--VALUES  ( 1 ),
--        ( 2 ),
--        ( 3 ),
--        ( 4 )
INSERT  INTO @InvoiceIdSet VALUES  ( -1 )

SELECT TOP 100
        I.Id ,
        Number ,
        DueDate ,
        IssuedDate ,
        Amount ,
        Test3
FROM    dbo.Invoices I
WHERE   I.ID IN ( SELECT    S.ID
                  FROM      @InvoiceIdSet S
                  WHERE     NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                                         FROM   @InvoiceIdSet
                                         WHERE  ID = -1 )
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT    S.ID
                  FROM      dbo.Invoices S
                  WHERE     EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                                     FROM   @InvoiceIdSet
                                     WHERE  ID = -1 ) )
```

It performs well for ALL and SOME scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

If `or S.ID=-1` is added, the SQL Server knows that the condition is true for each row; therefore, the query plan will use Scan as in your second plan.
As Martin Smith says in the comment, the SQL Server isn't clever enough in this situation. You need to either have 2 queries (one if -1 is there, other if only some rows are selected). That way, the SQL Server can produce 2 plans and both of them will be optimal for the scenarios they cover.
You could also go with recompilation (but RECOMPILE will be done always, which is a waste of the resources, in general). Or you can construct the query dynamically. Dynamically would mean you'd generate only 2 queries and both of them will be cached, so no recompilation but then caution how it's written so it isn't vulnerable to SQL injection.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are doing a trick here by supplying a minus 1 as a parameter as a way of getting everything.

I'm assuming this is in a Stored Proc or something, so maybe supply a null as a parameter in this scenario and try the following;

```
DECLARE @IDparam int

SELECT TOP 100
            I.Id ,
            Number ,
            DueDate ,
            IssuedDate ,
            Amount ,
            Test3
    FROM    dbo.Invoices I
    JOIN @InvoiceIdSet S ON S.ID = I.Id AND COALESCE(@IDparam, I.Id) = I.Id
```

If `@IDParam` is null, it will use `I.Id` in the where clause.  Might speed it up.

Comment: Interesting, but AND would not work. If IdSet contains only one record, with value of -1, the JOIN will not return any records.

Comment: Agree but the technique may be useful if you want one sql statement to do your searching. Or just do 2 queries as others have mentioned.  Don't know if you are in the C# Entity Framework workspace, but this stuff is trivial to do with LINQ.

Comment: Yes, I wish I could use EF and LINQ method chains. This would be a walk in the park.